# Docker container with published port not accessible from outside

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, port, dockerfile

My Docker container is running Rails on port `3000`, and I'm publishing the port to port `8900`. See:

> $ docker-compose ps
>
> ```
> Name                    Command               State            Ports
> rails_poc_1   /bin/sh -c puma -C config/ ...   Up       0.0.0.0:3000->8900/tcp
> ```

However, when visiting `http://localhost:8900` my browser displays `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

When `curl`ing port `3000` from inside the container with `docker exec 8fcceed1d477 curl localhost:3000` I get a valid response which proves Rails is working properly.

Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have your port mapping reversed.  Your ps line should look more like:

0.0.0.0:8900->3000/tcp

If you want to access 3000 outside the container as 8900